# C#: Capturing values in datagridview not working properly

Tags: c#

I'm having a bit of a problem with getting values from DataGridView in C#.

I'm currently using this code for example:

```
private void GridView_Discount_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Label_DiscountID.Text = GridView_Discount.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Field_DiscountName.Text = GridView_Discount.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Field_DiscountRate.Text = GridView_Discount.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }
```

...and it actually works.

However, it only works when I click the part of the cell with value in it, but when I click on the part of the cell which is a white space, it doesn't capture the data. I am resizing the cells so it would fit the DataGridView component.

Also, I made the `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`, so once I click one of the cells, it selects the full row, but still, it won't work when I click on the white spaces.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try handling [`CellClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) instead of [`CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx).

From the links, the `CellClick` event:

> Occurs when any part of a cell is clicked.

`CellContentClick`:

> Occurs when the content within a cell is clicked.